# .htaccess request url parameters like subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to pass url parameters like subdirectory

My original link : `www.example.com/API/files.php?dir=events/12&file=a.jpg`
I want : `www.example.com/API/files/events/12/a.jpg`

Folder Structure :

.

```
└── var/
    └── www/
        └── html/
            ├── API/
            │   ├── files.php
            │   └── .htaccess
            ├── index.html
            └── .htaccess
```

Root level .htaccess

```
#var/www/html/.htaccess

DirectoryIndex view.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts, could you please elaborate more on your this statement please `It's working But if i put files.php into any other subfolder it's not working like this` for better understanding of question.

Comment: if i have files.php in root directory it's above htaccess is working fine. But if i move files.php into any other sub directory it's not working.

Comment: I would like to request you please don't keep changing question why because now this has become totally different question from your starting one.

Comment: It appears that you have 2 `.htaccess`. Can you post content from both of them in question

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Since OP saying that API URL should work too, so adding htaccess rules for that now.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^files/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+\.jpg)/?$ /files.php?dir=$1/$2&name=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/API/files/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+\.jpg)/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /files.php?dir=%1/%2&name=%3 [L]
```

---

---

Could you please try following, based on your shown attempts. Please make sure you clear the cache of your browser after placing these rules into your .htaccess file. I believe you need to remove `/` before your files.php which makes is think that your path always starts from root path, kindly try it once.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?files/(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ files.php?dir=$1&name=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /files\.php\?name=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?files\.php$ files/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225712/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-htaccess-request-url-parameters-like-su).